# Nifi memory continues to expand

Tags: apache-nifi

I used a three-node nifi cluster, the nifi version is 1.16.3, the hardware is 8core 32G memory, and the solid-state high-speed hard disk is 2T. OS is CentOS7.9, ARM64 hardware architecture.
The initial configuration of nifi is xms12g and xmx12G(bootstrip.conf).

Native installation, docker is not used, and only nifi installed on all thoese machines, using integrated zookeeper.

Run 20 workflow everyday from 00:00 to 03:00, and the total data size is 1.2G. Collect csv documents to the greenplum database.

My problem now is that the memory usage of nifi is increasing every day, 0.2G per day, and all three nodes are like this. Then the memory is slowly full and then the machine is dead. This procedure is about a month（when the memory is set to 12G.）.

That is to say, I need to restart the cluster every month. I use a native processor and workflow.

I can't locate the problem. Who can help me?
I may have any descriptions. Please feel to let me know,thanks.

I have made the following attempts:

1. I set the initial memory to 18G or 6G, and the speed of workflow processing has not changed. The difference is that, after setting it to 18G, it will freeze for a shorter time.
2. I used openjre1.8, and I tried to upgrade it to 11, but it was useless.
3. i add the following configuration, and is also useless:

> java.arg.7=-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m
> java.arg.8=-XX:CodeCacheMinimumFreeSpace=10m
> java.arg.9=-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing

Every day's timing tasks consume little resources. Even if the memory is adjusted to 6G, 20 tasks run at the same time, the memory consumption is about 30%, and it will run out in half an hour.

Comment: What processors are you using? My first bet is executescript issue... Does it help if you restart processors?

Comment: @daggett thanks for the reply.
Restarting doesn't help, even if I stop and delete the workflow, it doesn't make it take less memory!

Processor:
ListSFTP
FetchSFTP
LogAttribute
UpdateAttribute
SplitText
ControlRate
ConvertRecord
JoltTransformJSON
UpdateRecord
PutKudu
InvokeHTTP. 

ControlServices:

CSVReader
JsonTreeReader
JsonRecordSetWriter
DBCPConnectionPool
AvroSchemaRegistry

Comment: Nothing custom... Bad. How you are monitoring memory consumption? How many threads you set for nifi?

Comment: @daggett thanks for the reply.
i used two ways, one is the monitoring panel of nifi itself. the other is to add jmx to the bootstrap configuration file, -javaagent=...jmx_mprometheus_agent.jar.... , using prometheus+grafana to monitor. Then it also monitors the overall operation information of the machine with node_exporter.
In terms of thread, the default configuration has not been modified. i can see that the default is that the ready-made thread on each node is 10. Through the history, the thread is sometime full, but not always. 
Any configuration suggestions? tks

Comment: what thread settings do you have in `sandwich menu -> controller settings -> general` ?

Comment: if your machine is nearing its limit could you maybe do a memory snapshot and examine the results? something is causing some sort of memory leak, Im interested to know how this issue can be resolved

Comment: @daggett sorry for late reply.  
time driven thread: 10, 
max event driven thread: 1. 
Should I turn it up? 

I think I should have omitted to describe important information. I thought it was irrelevant.
I started and stopped the workflow by accessing the Rest API, not through the scheduler of nifi itself. Nifi is just a component of our application system.
In the last week's test show, noheap memory metaspace has been growing. When I limit it (-XX: metaspaceSize=512m), it is easy to see the death of the nifi node (SocketTimeout).

Comment: @coding_potato Yes, I have really started to do this, but I haven't located the problem yet. Thank you for your prompt.

Comment: 10 is number of processor instances working at the same time - or number of files processed at the same time. As for me it's a low number. Could you publish an image with memory consumption pattern during a period of time? How many files are running through your flow per min?